# How to display the category part before the delimiter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to seperate the text I have on my `woocoomerce catagory` page by a delimiter.

I can see in my `archive-product.php` page that,

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
```

But I don't want to echo the whole thing at one place. I want to display the part before the delimiter in the top and the part after the delimiter in the bottom.

Coding example of what I would like to do:

```
$explode_arr = explode('||', $text_from_category_page);

//Top of page
echo $explode_arr[0];

//Bottom of page
echo $explode_arr[1];
```

Comment: You can't explode() a hook just like this. What do you wish exactly to display in top and bottom of your template *archive-product.php*?. Try to be more explicit updating your question. The hook `woocommerce_archive_description` is used within 2 functions located in plugin *woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php*:  [function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description()](http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description/) and [function  woocommerce_product_archive_description()](http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_product_archive_description/)…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - Thanks for your time. I have updated the question, hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - don't know if it is the right way to do it, but it works!

```
$explode_arr = explode('[delimiter]',category_description());

echo $explode_arr[0];
echo $explode_arr[1];
```